# Bower ECMDERR - other solutions not working

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

I'm trying to run bower install on a Windows 8.1 machine, and as soon as it tries to git the first file it dies with exit code 128. I have tried the following, as suggested in other SO threads:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

In Windows Firewall, adding inbound rules for port 22, port 9418, and git.exe in general, and outbound rules for the same, as well as turning it off entirely.

Deleting c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache

The only thing I've found that can work is to manually run `git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:path/to.git` but I'll have to do that on every single file every single time, and that's going to be incredibly tedious and is not actually a solution. Anyone have anything more functional? Is there, for instance, a way to change how bower pulls files to rewrite the path to the one that works?

Comment: This seems to be a open bower-issue: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/50 Did you already try to temporarily turn your firewall completely off?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my original post. "... as well as turning it off entirely."

Comment: Oh - sorry, overread that.. :/

Comment: No worries. I'd rather too many questions than not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem is that I had to reinstall msysgit to allow command prompt git, not just git bash git, as per the note for Windows users at github.com/bower/bower - bower has now successfully installed my files for me.

So for anyone else who might encounter the same problem in the future, make sure you selected the correct option when installing msysgit; it will save you some headaches.