# bower ECMDERR Failed to execute git ls-remote --tags,

Tags: git, bower-install

I'm new to *bower* and *git*, and i got this error when I ran `bower install` command in my  AngularJs project directory:

```
bower ECMDERR Failed to execute git ls-remote --tags,
```

I tried most popular solution such as:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

and also installed msysgit to allow *command prompt* git as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660675/bower-ecmderr-other-solutions-not-working) but still getting the same error.

Has anyone faced the same issue? By the way, I'm running on Win7 64-bit machine.

Comment: I'm on Win Svr 2012 64-bit popular solution worked for me. 
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
I did check to make sure git config was in c:\users\MYUSERNAME Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789683/howto-fix-bower-ecmderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. I don't know why but somehow my default folder for Git is on "H:" drive so my ".gitconfig" file is on it.  I'm guessing that's why the git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// didn't take effect because of .gitconfig location. 
Everything was solved after i moved ".gitconfig" file to "C:/Users/logged in user".